# QT Creator вместо сборки исполняемого файла собирается файл разделяемой библиотеки

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при сборке QT-проекта через `qt-creator->сборка проекта` вместо исполняемого файла собирается файл разделяемой библиотеки:

`file QuckLesson

QuckLesson: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d976b3b965cd47bfefc4efa17345c7a6e06a73ea, not stripped`

QuckLesson.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = QuckLesson
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += core gui qml
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
HEADERS += bhacasing.h brinecalc.h mudmixing.h weighting.h
SOURCES += bhacasing.cpp brinecalc.cpp main.cpp mudmixing.cpp weighting.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

В итоге файл, который собрался, может запускаться только из-под консоли. Подскажите почему происходит сборка не исполняемого файла при указании `TEMPLATE = app`или где может быть ошибка?

Comment: разделяемая библиотека, это как я понимаю, so. so запустить нельзя (и даже с под консоли). Значит все таки выполняемый. Поэтому, думаю, что в main.cpp Вы просто не создаете окна.

Comment: Дело в том что при запуске из-под qtcreator программа прекрасно работает и проблем с окном нет.

Comment: Потому что она не находит нужных so.

Comment: получается мне в папку, в которой находится исполнительный файл, нужно перекинуть библиотеки которые я подключаю? но беда в том, что я кроме QT-шных библиотек ничего не подключаю. И тогда еще один вопрос: если у меня этот файл запускается из-под консоли банальным `./QuckLesson` и потом появляется окно программы и сама программа работает корректно, то зачем этому файлу еще какие-то библиотеки? Тогда бы, логично предположить, что и из консоли он не запускался, а ругался на отсутствие каких либо библиотек. А этого не происходит.

Comment: а как же он тогда "не запускается"?

Comment: если я делаю двойной клик по файлу, то происходит следующее курсор начинает отображать что происходит запуск приложения (пиктограмма курсора "превращается" в  часы) и спустя секунд пятнадцать курсор становиться "обыкновенным курсором". И тоже самое при запуске  через правую кнопку `открыть с помощью... -> LXTerminal`.  Но если я открываю консоль и запускаю эту программу `./QuckLesson`, то она запускается без проблем. Единственно на что иногда ругается при запуске из консоли это за не правильную разметку в qml-файле, но тем не менее программа все равно работает без проблем.

Comment: вот сейчас сделал `qmake -poject` , `qmake` , `make` . Получил ошибку: `g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o build-QuckLesson-Desktop-Release qrc_qml.o   -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
make: *** [Makefile:196: build-QuckLesson-Desktop-Release] Ошибка 1` но qtcreator собирает без оповещения о данной ошибки. `16:26:55: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.`

Comment: по поводу запуска - думаю, что все в том, какие директории в PATH и текущая. А вот то, что оно не собирается - видимо не попал файл с main

Comment: видимо Вы правы.. при сборки через консоль (qmake, make) ругается на подключаемый файл QQmlAplicationEngine в main.cpp. Видимо дело в PATH или в указаниях путей...  Теперь придется разбираться  в данной проблеме...